# Hostname of EC2 Instance changed

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hostname

I noticed that the hostname of my EC2 instance changed. A few days ago, when I executed the command: echo $HOSTNAME, it was xxx.xx.xx.xx.somethingsomething.com and now when I executed the same command: echo $HOSTNAME it was just xxx.xx.xx.xx. I just want to know what may have caused the change of my hostname.

Comment: Is this the public or private hostname? Go to the ec2 page and click on the instance it will have values for "Public DNS" and "Private DNS", which one are you being given?

Comment: have you restarted your instance? or stopped and again started?
till you will not give permanent name or IP it will keep on changing once you will restart or stop and start your instance.

Comment: Yes I have restarted it but the change in hostname is not that frequent. I have at some point stopped and started again my instance. Is there a way to make the hostname unchangeable/permanent?